# memberOf vs. groupMembership in LDAP (Liferay)

Tags: ldap, liferay, liferay-6, ldap-query, ldapconnection

What is the difference b/n memberOf attribute and groupMembership attribute when used in LDAP Authentication settings in Liferay?

The users are imported successfully.
The groups are also imported successfully.

But the users are not assigned to the groups automatically. And when I changed the group variable from 'groupMembership' to 'memberOf', several users are not able to login to Liferay.

What exactly are memberOf and groupMembership variables?

[image: LDAP Liferay Settings]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`memberOf` is not a "variable", it is an attribute, or more accurately, it is a virtual attribute, or a dynamic attribute generated on the fly by some directory servers, but not all. Some use `memberOf` to use in search filters or in the attribute list of a search request, some use `isMemberOf` for the same purpose, some support both or neither, and there are probably other idioms of which I am not aware.

Generally speaking, to determine group membership, issue a search request to the directory server and specify `memberOf` or `isMemberOf` to be returned in the attribute list. Here is an example using a modern `ldapsearch` command line tool:

```
ldapsearch --port 1389 --baseDn 'ou=people,dc=example,dc=com' \
     --sizeLimit 3 --searchScope one --bindDn 'cn=directory manager' \
     --bindPasswordFile ~/.pwdFile '(uid=user.0)' isMemberOf
dn: uid=user.0,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
isMemberOf: cn=Dynamic Home Directories,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
isMemberOf: cn=bellevue,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
isMemberOf: cn=shadow entries,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
isMemberOf: cn=persons,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

This search response indicated that `user.0` is a member of the listed groups.

To reverse the sense of the query, that is, to determine which entries are the member of a group, use the `isMemberOf` or `memberOf` with an assertion in the filter used in the search request:

```
ldapsearch --port 1389 --baseDn 'ou=people,dc=example,dc=com' \
   --sizeLimit 3 --searchScope one --bindDn 'cn=directory manager' \
   --bindPasswordFile ~/.pwdFile \
  '(isMemberOf=cn=persons,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com)' 1.1
dn: uid=terrygardner,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com

dn: uid=user.0,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com

dn: uid=user.1,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com

dn: uid=user.10,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
```

This search response indicates that there are several member of the group whose distinguished name is `cn=persons,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com`.

While not specific to [LifeRay](http://www.liferay.com/), the above is a general explanation of one way to deal with group membership and also of reverse group membership from an LDAP perspective.

Comment: Although you haven't directly answered my question, you gave me more than enough info so that I could understand what it's all about. Thanks Terry. Appreciate it.