# checking if a user belongs to a group in ldap

Tags: ldap

I'm new to LDAP and have a question.I want to check if particular user belongs to a particular group or not. i figured out how to query the ldap server.So it is right now able to check if the user exists on the server or not. but i couldn't figure out how to check  the user with the right group (line below is what i have used)

```
l_retval := DBMS_LDAP.search_s(l_session,l_ldap_base, DBMS_LDAP.scope_subtree, 'objectclass=*', l_attrs, 0, l_message);
```

My main purpose is to authorize users of a particular group (not authenticate)

I have two bases-one for authorization `(uid=anders,ou=ourusers,o=company)` and one for the groups `(cn=programmers,ou=groups,o=company)`

Could anyone please guide me so as how to proceed!

Answer (score 1):

Use this filter, and make the search DN to be the DN of the group you want to check with.

```
(&(objectClass=*)(member=[userDN]))
```

The `[userDN]` is the full DN of the user to search for like `cn=bob,ou=bar,o=foo`. It won't work if it is not a full DN. If you just have a username, first get a DN of the user, and then use this filter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `memberOf` or `isMemberOf` to determine if an entry is a member of a group. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187994/memberof-vs-groupmembership-in-ldap-liferay/7191490#7191490) question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in the active directory too, but I have the feeling that skipping one generation, and directly use **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement** is the way to go.
One article I'be been reading is:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx
I'll try to get back to your question later 
There also seems to be a bug in the verion 4 of the .Net framework: it will bug if there is a group in the group you are looking at. Maybe a correction in version 4.5.